# How to loop over all subplot in a figure to add a new series in it?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Doing the following allow me to create a figure with subplots :

```
DF.plot(subplots=True, layout=(9,3),figsize = (20,40),sharex=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This works very well. However, I would like to add to all these subplots a new series that would be the same for each subplot.

I think it is possible by browsing all subplot in the figure and then edit each one.
I don't know how to do it and don't know the smartest way to do it, maybe avoid using loop would be faster but I don't know if it is doable.

Assuming that the common serie is `DF2['Datas']`, how do I add it to all subplots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) returns a `matplotlib.axes.Axes` or `numpy.ndarray` of them.

```
axs = DF.plot(subplots=True, layout=(9,3),figsize = (20,40),sharex=False)

for ax in axs.ravel():
   DF2['Datas'].plot(ax=ax)
```